# Recording Resource Usage with Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to record bandwith with nginx? The goal I am trying to achieve is when images, videos, or audio files are download, that the resource utilization is tracked somewhere. Is this possible with Nginx?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to separately measure how much bandwith is generated by assets separately from web app itself? Or just to know total server traffic?

Comment: How much bandwidth is generated by assets separately from the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not have a built-in tools for this, but you can set up a separate access log for assets and parse it for request size on the fly (for example by logstash into graphite)

```
log_format sizes_only '$bytes_sent';
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|mp4/OtherWayToDetectAssets) {
   access_log /some/log/location sizes_only;
}
```